# Bootstrap buttons don't center

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've built this buttons with Bootstrap, but they don't center. 
I will attach a photo with the problem. I'm new to bootstrap because I was writing the css by myself. [buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Mdvz.png)
Code:

### HTML/CSS

```css
  .social {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 10px;
  position: absolute;
}

.fa-social {
  background: #2098f5;
  border: 0px solid #2098f5;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  height: 42px;
  line-height: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 42px;
}

.fa-social:hover {
  color: #2098f5;
```

```html
<div class="social">
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x fa-social"></i></a>
  <a href="https://www.twitter.com"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x fa-social"></i></a>
  <a href="https://www.linkedin.com"><i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-2x fa-social"></i></a>
  <a href="https://www.plus.google.com"><i class="fa fa-google-plus fa-2x fa-social"></i></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Also, why didnt you add the btn class to those anchors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple add the class `btn` to your anchor(a) tags like below

```
        <div class="social">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="icon-facebook fa-2x fa-social"></i></a>
            <a href="https://www.twitter.com" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="icon-twitter fa-2x fa-social"></i></a>
            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="icon-linkedin fa-2x fa-social"></i></a>
            <a href="https://www.plus.google.com" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="icon-google-plus fa-2x fa-social"></i></a>
        </div>
```

> Note: Here i have also used `btn-primary` for just color you can skip or set default.

Comment: If i do this I have to edit the margin and the padding, after that all my buttons mess up.

Comment: I did it, added another class so I could remove the padding and margins, but it still doesn't center.

Comment: show us your complete code or give us reference link

Comment: @octnic buttons are in center, check your fiddle, i have updated your code there https://jsfiddle.net/ny02pvpg/2/

Comment: @octnic if it resolved your problem than vote and accept the answer to close and to help anyone who have the same issue in future.

Answer (score 1):

```
Changed your CSS a little. Run the snippet below.
```

```css
.social {
    text-align: center;
   margin: 0 auto;
}

.fa-social {
    background: #2098f5;
    border: 0px solid #2098f5;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    height: 42px;
    line-height: 45px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 42px;
}

.fa-social:hover {
      color: #2098f5;
      }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="social">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x fa-social"></i></a>
            <a href="https://www.twitter.com"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x fa-social"></i></a>
            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com"><i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-2x fa-social"></i></a>
            <a href="https://www.plus.google.com"><i class="fa fa-google-plus fa-2x fa-social"></i></a>
        </div>
```

Comment: You're right. I only checked on a smaller screen. Check my updated code now.

Comment: It's the same code I think because nothing changed for me. Did you edit it?

Comment: It's still not centered, that's what I mean.

Comment: I'm not sure whats centered for you. The screen shot shows the div in the center of the page. May be you want something else but that right there is center. Can you elaborate what exactly you are doing and where the div should be

Comment: oh.... my fault. I wanted the logos of facebook, twitter and so on to be centered in their squares. I'm really sorry for my bad exprimation.

Comment: oh well. then i guess santosh has already answered the question for you. goodluck!

Answer (score 0):

Try the replacing your `.social` CSS element with the following one:

```
.social {
   text-align: center;
   margin: 0 auto;   
}
```